# How to save the plot with the labels and ticks area transparent but not the main plot area in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a plot with the labels area (the area where you print the xlabel, ylabel and title) transparent and the main plot (the area where you plot the data) not transparent.

[image]

I'm using the transparent command in savefig:

```
plt.savefig("name",tranparent=True)
```

The problem is that this makes all the figure transparent.

In the documentation says this about the transparent argument:

> transparent : bool
>
> If True, the axes patches will all be transparent; the figure patch will also be transparent unless facecolor and/or edgecolor are specified via kwargs. This is useful, for example, for displaying a plot on top of a colored background on a web page. The transparency of these patches will be restored to their original values upon exit of this function.

So I tried changing the `facecolor` and `edgecolor` arguments, but I can't find a combination that gives the plot that I want.

Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10939) in the newest version of matplotlib. I'm not sure if this applies to here, because you do not state which version you are using.

The workaround would be to use a transparent facecolor and leave the other arguments at their defaults.

```
fig.savefig("fname", facecolor=(1,1,1,0))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. The matplotlib version that I have is 1.5.1